Optimizing a ClickHouse Materialized View for High Cardinality Columns in Large Dataset
I have a table with 12 columns. Every day, we get like 350 million rows and for a month, we get around 8 billion rows. Mostly, we query last 1 month of data.
Column A - timestamp
Column B to G - will be used in filters and group by statements. Low cardinality columns.
Columns H to J - will be used in filters. High cardinality columns.
Columns K and L - used in aggregation. We use only sum() function
If I use materialized view by grouping columns from A to G, I was able to reduce the no. of rows to around 15 million per day. But I couldn't perform filters on columns H to J. Adding columns H to J to the materialized view didn't help as the records count didn't go below 300 million per day.
My approach:
Use materialized view if columns H to J are not used in filters.
If columns H to J are used, then query the raw table.
Can someone please suggest some good approach?
